# PHP POST values from selected textboxes

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to create a comparison page/form using a combination of PHP, HTML and jQuery. The ideal effect I like to create as below

```
<form>
    left       |    right
    [text1.l]  |    [text1.r]
    [text2.l]  |    [text2.r]
    submit
</form>
```

Where `[]` denotes an input text box. For a particular use case, the user select would select either the left or right textbox for each row and post the form. Essentially I am only interested in the value of the text box selected when I process the form.

I was thinking of perhaps using a radio button as I only allow selection of one box per row, but I am unsure how set this up to retrieve the text box value.

Any helps would be appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/Bq8AF/

**Form**

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" class="form">
<fieldset id="left">Left
    <input type="text" name="foo-left-1" size="50" />
    <input type="text" name="foo-left-2" size="50" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="right">Right
    <input type="text" name="foo-right-1" size="50" />
    <input type="text" name="foo-right-2" size="50" />
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JS + jQuery**

```
$("input[type=text], textarea").focus(function(){
    // Check for the change from default value
    if(this.value == this.defaultValue){
        this.select();
    }

    // get the name of the field, e.g. foo-left-1
    //alert(this.name);
    var fieldNameSplitted = this.name.split("-");

    // recombine + switch "left" to "right" and vice versa
    var fieldNameOtherSide = '';

    // the ident remains the same (e.g. foo-)
    var fieldNameOtherSide = fieldNameSplitted[0] + "-";

    // left/right switch (e.g. foo-left, gets foo-right and vv)
    if(fieldNameSplitted[1] == 'left') { fieldNameOtherSide += 'right-'; }
    if(fieldNameSplitted[1] == 'right') { fieldNameOtherSide += 'left-'; }

    // row number (e.g. foo-right-2)
    fieldNameOtherSide += fieldNameSplitted[2];

    // now we have the name of the field on the other side of the row, right?
    //alert(fieldNameOtherSide);

    // use that as jQuery selector and disable the element
    // because  the user has selected the other one
    // and when the form is send disabled fields will not be send
    // http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled
    $('input[name=' + fieldNameOtherSide + ']').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

- The user selects the textbox by click.
- When "submit" is clicked, a browser will only send the not-disabled fields.
  The $_POST array will only contain the values from all not-disabled fields.
- When a user enters this:
  [image]
  you would get `$_POST['foo-right-1'] = 'car'` and `$_POST['foo-left-2'] = 'dog'`.

Comment: Yes, but $_POST['right-article-1'] only get me "1" etc, opposed to the textbox value associated with that radio button. Which is what I am interested in.

Comment: Úse a textarea: <input type="text" name="left-textbox-1" /> - updated the example code accordingly and added a jsfiddle.

Comment: How does this even allow the user to select whether they want to submit the left or right value?